# Should $scope be used when not needed from html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When you are in a controller and need to create a variable or function that **will not be used from html**. Should you still put it in $scope?

```
$scope.myFunction = function(){
     //(...)
     return true;
}
```

or

```
var myFunction = function(){
    //(...)
    return true
}
```

Comment: You should generally avoid it. Use scope only for model data that needs view binding or watches.

Comment: The first one is more testable.

Comment: For testability we can define the function on the controller itself, `this.myFunction`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope` can be seen as a glue between your html and your controllers. It solely purpose is to be able to put something on it and be able to access it on the view or controller.

So if you need something only on the controller, you don't need to put it on the `$scope`, because the view doesn't need to access it.

Even when putting it on the `$scope` is more testable, it is not a good idea because you're changing your code doing something "not that good" just for testing sake.

Normally (angular is all about use cases) the better idea when you find that you have this "private" methods is to create a service. Service is not only to share data, it is also used to do the business logic behind your data. Feel free to put your bindings to the controller and delegate the work to a service. That way to get a thin controller and testable components.

Answer (score 0):

If your view is not using it, you need not (and should not) put it on $scope.

**From testing point of view**:- If myFunction is not exposed to public (through your view in this case), you won't test it directly anyways (you don't unit test private methods), but the tests will be indirectly included in the tests you will write for the public function from which myFunction is accessed.
So, you don't need to put it on the $scope even when keeping testing in mind.